# How can I change width of a specific label in my program, No inline style is allowed only to control from head

Tags: css, html, label

This is the label and I want to change its width from style defined in my style rule in the `<head>` .

```
<label for="gender">Gender:</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required>Female
```

Answer (score 1):

By using this: `label[for="gender"] { display: inline-block; width: 200px;}`

Inline elements like a `<label>` is displayed so that its height and width is calculated by the browser based on its content. If you want to control height and width you have to change those elements blocks (`display: inline-block` or `display: block`).

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/csgn6051/7/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
label[for='gender'] {
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<label for="gender">Gender:</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required>Female
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.